# Limiting distribution of an infinite Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, infinite-matrices

Let the following infinite matrix  **P** represent an Infinite States Markov Chain.

\begin{pmatrix} 1  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
1  & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots\\
0  & 1 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots\\
0  & 0 & 1 & 0 &  \cdots\\
0  & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}

My purpose is to find its limiting distribution.

So, as far as I know, I have to find a vector **x= (x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),...)** wich satisfies: **xP=x** and  **x(1)+x(2)+x(3)+...+x(i)+...= 1**

That **x** will be a stationary distribution for this chain.

That gives me the following equations:

```
x(1) + x(2) = x(1)

      x(3) = x(2)
           .
           .
           .
    x(n+1) = x(n)
```

Which results in:

x(1)=1

x(2)=x(3)=...=x(n)=...=0

So the stationary distribution is unique and it´s : **x=(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...)**

How can I know it is also the limiting distribution?

(sorry for the rude writting, I am new and some text commands did´t work)

Comment: Where does the chain start?

Comment: I´m only interested in the limiting distribution, so I really don´t care where it starts @kimchilover

Comment: If you start at 1, you'll never leave one, and the limiting distribution is what you gave.  But if you start anywhere else you'll march off to $\infty$, and not have a limiting distribution (or, formally, $x=(0,0,\ldots)$, if you will).

Comment: I think what will happen is that you´ll always reach one. For any state n @kimchilover

Comment: You're right; I misread the matrix.  Your $x$ is right.

Comment: The thing is that knowing x is a stationary distribution. How can I prove it is the limiting one? @kimchilover

Comment: @Ian's argument looks ok.  The $\ell_1$ distance between $pP^N$ and $x$ is at most $\sum_{i>N} p_i$ , which $\to0$ as $N\to\infty.$

Comment: Hola, @Miguel hace tiempo respondiste a mi primera pregunta por aquí y la verdad es que me ayudó mucho. Te menciono por si puedes echarle un ojo a esta. Soy un pringaillo de 1º de Física-Mates y me meto en líos como estos un poco fuera de mi alcance. Saludos y gracias de antemano(:

Answer (score 0):

Take any finitely supported initial distribution $p$; say the maximum of the support is at $N$. Then $p P^{N-1}$ is already the stationary distribution $\pi$. Now given any arbitrary initial distribution $q$ and $\epsilon>0$, $q$ is within $\epsilon$ in the $\ell^1$ metric of some finitely supported distribution $q_\epsilon$.

Lemma: for any infinite row-stochastic matrix $P$ and any row vectors $p,q \in \ell^1,\| pP - qP \|_{\ell^1} \leq \| p - q \|_{\ell^1}$.

Therefore there is $N(\epsilon)$ such that $\pi=q P^{N(\epsilon)-1}$, hence $q_\epsilon P^{N(\epsilon)-1}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $\pi$.